# Usar auto en la declaración de una función lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

¿Cuándo se puede usar auto en la declaración de una función lambda?
Si intento usar auto en el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
    const std::function<void()>* m_Lambda = nullptr;

public:
    A(const std::function<void()>& lambda) : m_Lambda(&lambda) {}

    void ExecuteLambda()
    {
        (*m_Lambda)();
    }
};

void main()
{
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "i1 == " << i1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "i2 == " << i2 << std::endl;
    };

    A a(lambda);
    a.ExecuteLambda();
}
```

Uso *Visual Studio Community 2019* y al empezar la ejecución de `a.ExecuteLambda()`, el programa se detiene con la siguiente excepción:

*Excepción no controlada en 0x76D9B5B2 en lambda.exe: excepción de Microsoft C++: std::bad_function_call en la ubicación de memoria 0x00B5F434.*

Si cambio la línea `const auto lambda = [&]()` por `const std::function<void()> lambda = [&]()`, funciona perfectamente.
¿Por qué no permite usar *auto*?¿Se puede cambiar algo para que permita usarla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el lambda no es del tipo que tu crees. El lambda no es del
tipo `std::function<void()>`. Si vamos
a [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/0458f0b2)
puedes ver que en realidad es una clase, cuyo nombre asigna el compilador, que
sobrecarga el `operator()` entre otras cosas.

```cpp
class __lambda_22_25 {
public:
  inline /*constexpr */ void operator()() const {
    std::operator<<(std::cout, "i1 == ").operator<<(i1).operator<<(std::endl);
    std::operator<<(std::cout, "i2 == ").operator<<(i2).operator<<(std::endl);
  }

private:
  int &i1;
  int &i2;

public:
  // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_22_25(const __lambda_22_25 &) noexcept =
  // default; inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_22_25(__lambda_22_25 &&) noexcept =
  // default;
  __lambda_22_25(int &_i1, int &_i2) : i1{_i1}, i2{_i2} {}
};
```

Y cuando tu construyes el objeto tipo `A`, crea un `std::function`:

```cpp
const __lambda_22_25 lambda = __lambda_22_25{i1, i2};
A a = A(std::function<void ()>(__lambda_22_25(lambda)));
```

Donde radica el problema? Que el `std::function` que crea es un temporal. Y el
constructor de `A`:

```cpp
A(const std::function<void()>& lambda) : m_Lambda(&lambda) {}
```

Lo toma por referencia constante, y tu guardas la dirección de memoria en la
que estaba. **El problema es que estas guardando la dirección de memoria de un
temporal, que una vez haya corrido el constructor dejara de existir.**

Esto es comportamiento indefinido, así que es tan valido el error:

```
Excepción no controlada en 0x76D9B5B2 en lambda.exe:
excepción de Microsoft C++: std::bad_function_call en la ubicación de memoria 0x00B5F434.
```

Como que el programa corra ([clang y gcc son
ejemplos](https://godbolt.org/z/Ms7bMoMeE)), o como que el programa se detenga,
abra el navegador y te haga un rick roll. El el mundo del UB todo vale.

La solución es sencilla. No veo el motivo por el que quieras guardar un puntero
a un `std::function`, y claramente no es lo mejor. Guarda
una copia del `std::function` que te dieron. O usa un puntero directamente a la
función.